# MATLAB computer machine learning find best model to merge 3 signals into 1 known outcome

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I have ten measurements, containing 4 signals, with a length of 6-8 hours each at a sample rate of 10Hz. (200k-300k samples per measurement)

3 signals are the x-, y- and z-axis of an accelerometer (measuring the acceleration m/s^2). This sensor is positioned on a sphere. The sphere is inflated and deflated. The air-fluctuation in the sphere is the 4th signal.

The accelerometer values, are thus a representation of fluctuation of air in the sphere. If the sensor is positioned on top of the sphere, a good correlation is seen between air fluctuation and Z-axis of the accelerometer. The X- and Y- axis should in a perfect situation be 0, but they are not and contain noise.

I have tried many methods of combining the three signals into one, and comparing that to the air-fluctuation signal. At some points this does give a good outcomes, but when the accelerometer is not moving over one axis, the signal-noise ratio seems to be too high (e.g. when the sensor is at a 45 degree angle).

I am wondering if computer machine learning in Matlab can be used here, to automatically generate a model that makes the best fit: combine the 3 axis signals into one, that best represents the 4th signal. I assume this is what computer machine learning is about?

I can provide the signals in filtered format, the integrated signals, the angle of the sensor at a given time, full signal or just a minute of data, etc.

I have however no idea how to start and which toolbox to use to tackle this problem. Also what signals to feed into the algorithm? at what length (full vs couple of seconds/minutes)

**Can you help me getting started on the computer machine learning process, to use 3 signals (and/or formatted versions of them) into one signal that closely matches the fourth signal*.**

- I'm not asking for full code, but what steps to take to tackle this problem. Like have a look at that toolbox, and function x.

Comment: This isn't a coding service, it's a help service. Give it a shot and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, i'm asking what direction I need to go. I do understand how one can work with computer machine learning using static values, but I have no clue how to provide a signal (or part of it) and which toolbox to use for that.